# Extract data between two dates

Tags: excel

I have a bunch of data on the first sheet (`Manifest`) of my Excel file.

Like this:

[image]

On the `ByDate` sheet, I want to be able to put in two dates, and then display all the data between those two dates from the `Manifest` sheet. (Based on the date on `Column G` [named **DATE REQ'D**] for the `Manifest` sheet)

[image]

So I follow instruction by:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jcqN3swdW8&t=322s

On my cell `A7` (where I want the data to start) I put:

```
=IF(ROWS($A$7:A7)>C2,"",INDEX(Manifest!$G:$G,SMALL(IF(Manifest!$G:$G>=ByDate!$A$2,IF(Manifest!$G:$G<=ByDate!$B$2,ROW(Manifest!$G:$G)-ROW($A$7)+1)),ROWS(A$7:A7))))
```

For some reason, I don't get any data but the number `42741`. This can be seen in my second picture.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong and how to fix it?

Update:
I changed the cell's format to date. But my problems are:

1.The date that appeared is not in between the two dates. 
2. I thought when I dragged the cell across (copy without formatting) I would get the rest of the data such as order Number, customer...etc but I just get blank spaces:

[image: like this, without any actual data]

Comment: Format the result as a date and *42741* becomes *06-Jan-2017*.

Comment: So rereading your question, it sounds like you're trying to understand not why you're getting an unexpected number (which we explained is a date), but why you're not getting the result you expected based on your formula. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I thought I would be getting the data includes the order number,internal customer, retailer...in between these dates. But all I got is one date.

Answer (score 0):

While in cell `A7` on the `ByDate` worksheet, go to the `HOME` tab of your ribbon, then to the `Number` group and click the drop-down.

[image: Number Group]

Now select one of the date options (either `Short Date` or `Long Date`) to get your number to appear as a date.

[image: Number formats]

---

A quote from the Help guide for Excel: *Excel stores dates as sequential serial numbers so that they can be used in calculations.* That's why your date looks like a number instead of a date.

Comment: Can you check my update? I have changed it to date format, but I am not getting the data I want.